# Firebase function with dependency from private NPM registry

Tags: firebase, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gcloud

I would like to install dependency from private registry in TS app which will run in Firebase Function. I have .npmrc like below:

```
"@example:registry"="https://example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/"
"//example.com/api/packages/npm/:_authToken"="${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

But I don't know how to pass this NPM_AUTH_TOKEN variable to function builder. I tried:

```bash
NPM_AUTH_TOKEN=abc firebase deploy --non-interactive -f
```

But I got error:

```
  "original": {
    "name": "FirebaseError",
    "children": [],
    "exit": 1,
    "message": "Build failed: yarn install v1.22.19\nerror An unexpected error occurred: \"Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}\".\ninfo If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in \"/workspace/yarn-error.log\".\ninfo Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.; Error ID: 12c8ef4a",
    "status": 3
  }
```

Any hint how to provide this variable to function builder? Ideally, it should not be done manually as the deployment itself should take place on CI.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#using_private_modules), you are expected to embed the token in the file itself as it is not parsed. So maybe you can use your CI pipeline to construct the `.npmrc` file  dynamically and write it out to the build directory?

Answer (score 0):

What does your CI/CD look like? Assuming that you're all in on GC, you can use GC Secret Manager to store the auth token and then make that accessible in the Cloud Build environment (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets) for the deep dive).

Your file looks good. It's the processes around it that need to change.

If you want to test manually, open your terminal (assuming you're using Linux/Mac) and run the following:

`export NPM_TOKEN=abc`

Then run `firebase deploy --non-interactive -f` in the same terminal. That should now pull the npm token from your environment.